# One tap SMS verification API does not capture incoming SMS with OTP

Tags: android, api, mobile, one-time-password

I am trying to implement the [One tap SMS verification API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request).

I start the sms retriever in on CreateView

```
private val SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST = 2 


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_otp, container, false)
    registrationActivity().component.inject(this)

    val task = SmsRetriever.getClient(registrationActivity()).startSmsUserConsent(null)
    task.addOnSuccessListener { 
        Log.d(TAG, "SMS retriever successfully started")
    }
    task.addOnFailureListener {
        Log.e(TAG, "SMS retriever failed to start ${it.message}")
    }



    return rootView
}
```

this is the broadcast receiver which should launch the consent view

```
private val smsVerificationReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val extras = intent.extras
            val smsRetrieverStatus = extras?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status

            when (smsRetrieverStatus.statusCode) {
                CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                    // Get consent intent
                    val consentIntent = extras.getParcelable<Intent>(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT)
                    try {
                        // Start activity to show consent dialog to user, activity must be started in
                        // 5 minutes, otherwise you'll receive another TIMEOUT intent
                        startActivityForResult(consentIntent, SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST)
                    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                        // Handle the exception ...
                        Log.e(TAG,"something happened ${e.message}")
                    }
                }
                CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "timeout")
                    // Time out occurred, handle the error.
                }
            }
    }
}
```

and I register the broadcast receiver in onResume

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)
        activity!!.registerReceiver(smsVerificationReceiver,  intentFilter, SmsRetriever.SEND_PERMISSION,null)
        Log.d(TAG, "registered the sms verification receiver")
    }
}
```

I am receiving a SMS from a non-contact with the text "Your code is 221-222" but it doesn't get picked up. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request), a message triggers the broadcast only if it meets these criteria:

- The message contains a 4-10 character alphanumeric string with at least one number.
- The message was sent by a phone number that's not in the user's contacts.
- If you specified the sender's phone number, the message was sent by that number.

Since your code is `221-222` with a dash, it is not an alphanumeric string, the broadcast is not triggered. Converting your code to `221222` would trigger.